# PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR: column "name_id" cannot be cast automatically to type integer HINT: You might need to specify "USING name_id::integer"

Tags: postgresql, sqlite3-ruby

I experienced this error when I tried to run `rake db:migrate`.
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  column "developer_id" cannot be cast automatically to type integer
HINT:  You might need to specify "USING developer_id::integer".

I am changing my sqlite3 database to PostgreSQL for deployment in Heroku.
I am assuming the error is coming from the db/migrate file.rb that has the developer_id column specified.

```
  def change
    change_column :entries, :developer_id, :integer
  end
end
```

I will add any other document that may help locate the problem.

Comment: 1) What is the type for `developer_id` in SQLite? 2) What is actually stored in the field in SQLite? In SQLite it is possible to store mixed types in a column as it does not enforce the type, unless you specified [Strict](https://sqlite.org/stricttables.html).  **Add information as update to question**.

Comment: Solved the issue. It seems I just had extra code with unnecessary code. i.e unnecesary code containing developer_id